# get coefficients and features from a glmnet learner #mlr3

Tags: mlr3

Thanks for providing the mlr3 package in R , since I am trying it for the first time
simple code in mlr3:

learner = lrn("classif.cv_glmnet")
lrn_glmnet <- learner$train(task, row_ids = train_set).

my question is how to get the features and coefficients from lrn_glmnet object?
This also applies to other learners like log_reg
In general, how to get the feature importance and the scores from an mlr3 object after simple training or even resampling ?

Thanks,

Haneme

Comment: After training you can access them with `learner$model`.

Comment: Thanks Lars Kotthoff. This makes sense for glmnet and getting coefficients is straightforward but what about ksvm for example?. Is there something similar to featureImportance (the one in mlr)

Comment: Some learners implement methods to evaluate feature importance, see [the mlr3 book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/optimization.html#fs-var-imp-filters).